# Save file - xmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, streamwriter

I'm creating a method to serialize a file using this code:

```
public void Save(Object file, Type type, String path)
{
    // Create a new Serializer
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(type));

    // Create a new StreamWriter
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@path);

    // Serialize the file
    serializer.Serialize(writer, file);

    // Close the writer
    writer.Close();
}
```

But Visual Studio tells me this when I attempt to build:
"Error  1   The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  c:\users\erik\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FileSerializer\FileSerializer\Class1.cs 16  65  FileSerializer
"

Why is this?

**EDIT*

New code that works:

```
public void Save(Object file, String path, Type type)
{
    // Create a new Serializer
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);

    // Create a new StreamWriter
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);

    // Serialize the file
    serializer.Serialize(writer, file);

    // Close the writer
    writer.Close();
}

public object Read(String path, Type type)
{
    // Create a new serializer
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);

    // Create a StreamReader
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

    // Deserialize the file
    Object file;
    file = (Object)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    // Close the reader
    reader.Close();

    // Return the object
    return file;
}
```

read by calling:

```
myClass newClass = (myClass)Read(file, type);
```

Save by calling:

```
Save(object, path, type);
```

Thanks!
Erik

Comment: `new XmlSerializer(type);` + No need for `@` at `@path`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your error is in `new XmlSerializer(typeof(type));`. You don't need `typeof`. `new XmlSerializer(type);` is enough.

Since you serialize `file` object (and its type can be determined in the function) you don't have to pass its type. So your code can be re-written as

```
public void Save<T>(T file, String path)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(type);
```

instead of

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(type));
```

Answer (score 0):

`XmlSerializer` takes a `Type` parameter. `type` is already of type `Type`, so you don't need to call `typeof()` on it. `typeof()` is only needed when you're putting a class name or generic parameter inside the brackets.