# Need to make a button that saves all filled in textbox field, so i can load then in if needed

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to make an application that configures a holographic printer. The screen and layout are fixed now i need to configure it. I need a way that i can save all filled in data so i can load it days after it. But i cant find a way to do that

code behind

```
private void Save_as_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text file (*.txt)|*.txt|C# file (*.cs)|*.cs";
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, TBSOMS.Text);
}
```

Need to save filled content of. Combobox, TextBox, CheckBox and Buttons to a file.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Well i have multiple TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, CheckBoxes and Buttons. and right now it only saves the first TextBox

Comment: Easier way to do it would be to get an object ex: `Configuration` out of your inputs and serialize it, then just deserialize it whenever you need it [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your `Save_as_Click` method, you can get the file path using `SaveFileDialog`.

First step, create an object from your inputs

```
var config = new MyConfiguration();
config.Data1 = myCombobox.SelectedValue;
config.Data2 = myTextBox.Text;
config.Data3 = myCheckBox.IsChecked;
```

Then serialize this object using XMLSerializer

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyConfiguration));

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path)) // provide a path where you want to save your file
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, config);
}
```

Having that file you can use it whenever you want. Just deserialize it and you have your `MyConfiguration` object.

[Examples of XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)

[How to serialize an object to XML by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815813/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-by-using-visual-c)

Related `StackOverflow` questions:

[Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)

[Save file - xmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177445/save-file-xmlserializer)

Comment: Have fixed the problem on another way,   ```SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Text file (*.txt)";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(sfd.FileName)))
                {
                    write.WriteLine(TBSOMS.Text);
                    write.WriteLine(TBWVB.Text);
                    write.WriteLine(TBWNB.Text);
                    write.WriteLine(TBASPMM1.Text);```